# English name of "Maegami tomeru" (前髪とめ〜る)

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

"Maegami tomeru" (前髪とめ〜る) is a Japanese velcro-like product that keeps womens' hair in place.

Is there a commonly accepted English translation of this name?

[Bang Blocker](http://tyndall-effects.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/bang-blocker.html) found it hard to find a good translation

> Enter Dariya's Maegami Tomeru... Front Hair Stopper.  No.  Bang Blocker... Hmm... Fringe Foiler?
>
> Talking velcro and **** translations aside

A [trademark application](http://www.trademark247.com/maegami%2Btomeru-86054725-1.html) for the device said

> Goods and Services:
>
> Hair tapes; hair accessories, namely, devices for holding hair in
>   place, namely, hair grip sheets, hair barrettes, hair tapes and hair
>   ornaments; hook and pile fastening tapes

While a friend suggested "Fringe tape".

[image: Picture of packaging and product in use for the "before-the-hair fixer-in-placer" (Japanese literalish translation)]

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I do have a daughter. I'm not certain this product has made it to America. In what context are you writing about it?

Comment: I now have an image in my head of a gaggle of Japanese women walking down the street with toupée-like hairstyles held up by thick Velcro tape.

Comment: It's not available in the UK, as far as I'm aware. I guess we should just wait and see what the marketing guys decide to call it.

Answer (score 1):

I reverse Google image searched the picture you have and the first result is [Bangs Guard](http://eandata.com/lookup/4904651160075/), from a barcode search site, which itself links to [an Amazon page](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0012VQS4I) for the product.

It seems a USA-centric term, since BrE for *bangs* is *fringe*, but it is the English product name.